# What is it called when certain parts of the source code is executed during build for optimization?

Tags: javascript, optimization, next.js, build

I have noticed that next.js automatically optimizes my code, by evaluating/executing code during build, so that instead of it running every time the app runs, it only runs once during build.

For example, in my next.js project:

```js
  const string = (() => "Hello, World!")()

  console.log(string)
```

Is simply turned into:

```js
  console.log("Hello, World!")
```

What is the proper terminology for this? How does next.js know that this is ok to do?

How can it be configured in weback, esbuild, rollup etc?

---

I would like to accomplish this, becouse it will allow me to add certain static parameters in my project, and have the code use those parameters to build certain "structures", for example svg's, that are included in the build. I don't want these structures to be created every time i run the app, only once during build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example provided in OP, is called *Constant folding*. Read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding).